# jqtransform and option's click event

Tags: jquery, jqtransform

Im using [jqtransform](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqtransform) plugin.

```
<label>Select Redimentionné :</label>
    <select name="select2" class='mySelect'>
      <option value="opt1" onclick="clickme(1)">Big Option test line with more wordssss</option>
      <option value="opt2" onclick="clickme(2)">Option 2</option>
      <option value="opt3" onclick="clickme(3)">Option 3</option>
      <option value="opt4" onclick="clickme(4)">Option 4</option>
      <option value="opt5" onclick="clickme(5)">Option 5</option>
      <option value="opt6" onclick="clickme(6)">Option 6</option>
      <option value="opt7" onclick="clickme(7)">Option 7</option>
      <option value="opt8" onclick="clickme(8)">Option 8</option>
    </select>
<ul style="width: 253px; display: none; visibility: visible;">
  <li style=""><a index="0" href="#" class="">Big Option test line with more wordssss</a></li>
  <li><a index="1" href="#" class="">Option 2</a></li>
  <li><a index="2" href="#" class="">Option 3</a></li>
  <li><a index="3" href="#">Option 4</a></li>
  <li><a index="4" href="#" class="selected">Option 5</a></li>
  <li><a index="5" href="#">Option 6</a></li>
  <li><a index="6" href="#">Option 7</a></li>
  <li><a index="7" href="#">Option 8</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add this click event to li with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mySelect option').each(function(){
  //alert($(this).attr('onclick'));
  var att = $(this).attr('onclick');
  $('jqTransformSelectWrapper ul').find('a').attr('att');
  });
});
```

But a has not any onclick attr. How can I assign option attribute to a?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working out your request in alignment with the code provided, but considering that what you want is this:

```
$('jqTransformSelectWrapper ul').find('a').attr('onclick', att);
```

So, to walk through and try to be sure this is what you want, we take the `onclick` attribute of the `option` and apply it the `a` elements; however, what you probably want is to be more specific with the link you're selecting, [perhaps using an index](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), for instance:

```
$('jqTransformSelectWrapper li:eq(' + index + ')').find('a').attr('onclick', att);
```

Where you'd need to use the `index` argument that *would be* supplied as a parameter of the `each` call - t[he signature of which](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) would look like this:

```
$.each(..., function(index, value) { 

});
```

Comment: but 'a' still has not any attribute - only index - Thanks

Comment: @DjangoBitter I have updated the second version using `index`: it had a typo.